# Ограничение карты только по вертикали

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Подскажите пожалуйста, как ограничить листинг карты только по вертикали(чтобы не было видно серого поля), а бесконечный листинг по горизонтали оставить. Свойство restrictMapArea и метод setCorrection ограничивают карту и по вертикали и по горизонтали, что делает ее практически статической. Необходимо чтобы размеры карты были как на главной странице Яндекс -
https://yandex.ru/maps/?ll=126.265089%2C4.419700&z=2

Comment: Перфекционизм - дело неплохое... Но объясните, какая в целом ставится задача, кроме бесполезной прокрутки карты мира по горизонтали? Чем именно вас не устраивает карта, ограниченная со всех сторон?

Comment: На карте нужно расставить маркеры, при клике на которые карта перемещается и маркер становится по центру (это нужно для удобства работы с маркером(маркер - не просто иконка и все)). Если карта ограничена по горизонтали, то она не перемещается к маркеру. Для кого то прокрутка бесполезная, а для кого то она необходима, потому что так удобнее и красивее.

Comment: У вас при ограничении не работает myMap.panTo() или пара setCenter() + setZoom() ? Если так, можно пример - вдруг там баг и надо Яндексу писать, чтобы исправляли? Или проблема с перемещениями другого рода?